# run sql script in postgresql docker have included in DockerFile

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am learning to use docker, my goal is to create a postgres sql container in which i create a table, as of now i do not want to add any data just create the table. i was able to create a postgres sql instance but copy/add my sql script (which creates this table) to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ does not seem to work. i can confirm this when i run the psql db i cannot see any table created.

My Dockerfile

```
"FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y   postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

USER postgres

RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker

RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

EXPOSE 5432

VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]


copy /scripts/test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]"
```

My sql file

```
CREATE TABLE email_confirmation_code (
id integer NOT NULL,
code character varying(255) NOT NULL,
user_id integer
);
```

testing

```
psql -h localhost -p 32772 -U docker --password
Password for user docker: 
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-1.pgdg16.04+1), server 9.3.17)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

docker=# select * from email_confirmation_code
docker-# ;
ERROR:  relation "email_confirmation_code" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from email_confirmation_code
```

as you can see the table does not exist. please point out what is the mistake here.

Answer (score 6):

That's a feature of [the standard postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/); it's not something you get if you install PostgreSQL by hand in a plain Ubuntu container.

If you build a custom image for this, you can just start from that image and add your initialization file.  This is a complete Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
COPY ./scripts/test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I might not build a custom image for this.  Instead, you can use the `docker run -v` option or the Docker Compose `volumes:` option to push the script into the container when it starts up (treating it as a configuration file).

(Also remember that these init scripts only run the very first time the database container starts up; if there is already database data they will not re-run.)

Comment: Thanks. Your last comment helped me, I had to delete the volume of container 

$ docker volume rm docker_database_volume

.Finally re-create the image and the Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the files/folders inside `/var/lib/postgresql/data` volume and create a container.

Comment: can you please elaborate, i am creating the container in my local desktop. so do you want me to delete the files from my local computer's file system or from the containers file system

Comment: Inside the container, but please check @david-maze answer for better clarification